# Nginx wildcard subdomain

Tags: nginx

I have setup my nginx config file as:

```
server {
   server_name example.com www.example.com;
   listen 80;
   
   location = / {
     .....
  }
}

server {
  server_name *.example.com;
  listen 80;
  location = / {
      proxy_pass ...
  }
}
```

browsing through example.com and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) is fine, but when I use some subdomain like a.example.com or b.example.com I get a message like "301 moved permanently" and I am redirected back to example.com

Here is the actual file;

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;
     client_max_body_size 50M;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-image-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-xslt-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-mail.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_mail_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-stream.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_stream_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

types {
    text/html                             html htm shtml;
    text/css                              css;
    text/xml                              xml;
    image/gif                             gif;
    image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                js;
    application/atom+xml                  atom;
    application/rss+xml                   rss;

    text/mathml                           mml;
    text/plain                            txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor      jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                      wml;
    text/x-component                      htc;

    image/png                             png;
    image/tiff                            tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                    wbmp;
    image/x-icon                          ico;
    image/x-jng                           jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                        bmp;
    image/svg+xml                         svg svgz;
    image/webp                            webp;

    application/font-woff                 woff;
    application/java-archive              jar war ear;
    application/json                      json;
    application/mac-binhex40              hqx;
    application/msword                    doc;
    application/pdf                       pdf;
    application/postscript                ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                       rtf;
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl         m3u8;
    application/vnd.ms-excel              xls;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject         eot;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint         ppt;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc              wmlc;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml  kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz      kmz;
    application/x-7z-compressed           7z;
    application/x-cocoa                   cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff       jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file          jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                run;
    application/x-perl                    pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                   prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed          rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager  rpm;
    application/x-sea                     sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash         swf;
    application/x-stuffit                 sit;
    application/x-tcl                     tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert            der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall               xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                 xhtml;
    application/xspf+xml                  xspf;
    application/zip                       zip;

    application/octet-stream              bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream              deb;
    application/octet-stream              dmg;
    application/octet-stream              iso img;
    application/octet-stream              msi msp msm;

    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document    docx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet          xlsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation  pptx;

    audio/midi                            mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                            mp3;
    audio/ogg                             ogg;
    audio/x-m4a                           m4a;
    audio/x-realaudio                     ra;

    video/3gpp                            3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp2t                            ts;
    video/mp4                             mp4;
    video/mpeg                            mpeg mpg;
    video/quicktime                       mov;
    video/webm                            webm;
    video/x-flv                           flv;
    video/x-m4v                           m4v;
    video/x-mng                           mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                        asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                        wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                       avi;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.old:
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/billspree.work/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/billspree.work/privkey.pem;


server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        root /var/www/html/billspree.work;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html testing.html;
        server_name billspree.work www.billspree.work;

        location = / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }


        location ^~ /tenant {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:9003;
               # proxy_http_version 1.1;
               # proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
               # proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
               # proxy_set_header Host $host;
               # proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }


        location ^~ /tenant/portal {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:7172/prod/tenant/portal;
                # proxy_http_version 1.1;
                # proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                # proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                #proxy_set_header Host $host;
                #proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }


        #deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        #concurs with nginx's one

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
   # ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/billspree.work/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
   # ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/billspree.work/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
   # include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
   # ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
#    return 301 https://www.billspree.com$request_uri;  


}

server {
    listen [::]:80 ssl ipv6only=on;
    listen 80 ssl;
    server_name *.billspree.work;

    location = /portal {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:7172/portal;
    }
}

# test  server config with port 1027
server {

    server_name *.billspree.work;
    listen [::]:1027 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 1027 ssl; # managed by Certbot

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/billspree.work/fullchain.pem; # $
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/billspree.work/privkey.pem;
 #   include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  #  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

location ^~ / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

#server {
#    if ($host = billspree.work) {
#        return 301 https://www.$host$request_uri;
#    } # managed by Certbot
#    if ($host = www.billspree.work) {
#        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
#    } # managed by Certbot

#   server_name www.billspree.work billspree.work#
#       listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
#       listen 80;
#}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf:
# regex to split $uri to $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;

# Check that the PHP script exists before passing it
try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

# Bypass the fact that try_files resets $fastcgi_path_info
# see: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321
set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;

fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi.conf;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf:

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

Comment: Show full config with `nginx -T`. Also, make sure that `a.example.com` and `b.example.com` DNS records are pointing to the same server as `example.com` and `www.example.com`.

Comment: Actually, no subdomain is working in my case, not even www.example.com, only example.com is functional

Comment: There is no redirect configured in your nginx configuration. The redirect most probably comes from your backend server.

Comment: What backend server are we talking about here?

Comment: Whatever you proxy your requests to.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration for `*.billspree.work` is incorrect.

```
listen 80 ssl;
```

means that nginx is configured to use TLS on port 80, which is not a valid configuration.